# Session Variable Lost?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

From my logon screen I am storing the name that logged on in a Session variable.  But when a button is pressed to open a new page, the value in the Session variable is lost in my production environment, but it continues to work fine when testing/debugging.

Why does the value not record accurately in Production?

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.txtname.Text > 0)
    {
        Session["name"] = this.txtname.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
    }
}

//This is my page load event for page 2
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Session["name"].ToString());
}
```

**EDIT**
I do not see any entry in my webconfig file that mentions

```
<sessionState>
```

This is what my session state in IIS looks like
[image]

**EDIT #2**
I added this line to my webconfig file and in production the session variable info is still not displayed.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="80" />
```

Comment: Are you using IIS? If so, is the session set to inprocess mode?

Comment: Yes, I am using IIS.  Where would I check this?

Comment: In the IIS Manager there is a "Session State" setting for the machine under the ASP.Net heading that could provide this information. Is your production environment multiple servers that someone may be switching servers?

Comment: I'm assuming you would be using IIS 7+? If so, just go to the site node and select session state. There you can see the different options. Default is in process.

Comment: Is the production server running as a web garden?

Comment: @AndrewMorton - how would I check this?

Comment: is this.txtname indeed greater than 0? And why are you comparing a control to a Int32? If it works, which I don't see how it could, is not idiomatic. Wouldn't you compare against null?

Comment: @MatthewMartin - yes this.txtname is > 0.  It holds a value, in my test environment the value is produced on screen, but when I copy the files over to my production environment the value is not.

Comment: @RedLightGreenLight In IIS, find which application pool your website is using (it's in "Basic Settings..."). Then find that application pool and, in its "Advanced Settings...", check the value of "Maximum Worker Processes" under "Process Model". *Don't change it.* If it is set to 1 then it is not running as a web garden.

Comment: Still looks wrong-- a comparable with a .Text field. Anyhow, explicitly set the sessionState in webconfig. Without that, you have no control over sesssionState, it could be disabled by the root app, machine.config, who knows. If you explicitly write your own sessionState, then you know what you are dealing with, otherwise you are relying on config inheritence.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Maximum Worker Processes is set to 1

Comment: @MatthewMartin - I am not opposed to explicitly writing my own session state, in this instance all I need is for the value entered in this.txtname to be avaliable to other pages in the web app

Comment: @RedLightGreenLight I think MatthewMartin meant for you to explicitly add a <sessionState> section to your web.config. [This example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) will suffice for now.

Comment: Don't implement a custom session state provider. That is unnecessary.

Comment: What happens if you comment out  if (this.txtname > 0)? Does this even compile?

Comment: Commenting out that line will compile.

Answer (score 0):

The value of session is lost because of Redirect action. You can read more for example [here](http://mmtripathi.blogspot.com/2008/09/session-lost-problem-after.html).

Use `Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx", false);`

Comment: Even though it successfully works on my test environment it is still due to the false parameter being omitted from Response.Redirect()?

Comment: Is your test environment using the precise same version of IIS and configuration as production? If you go through Visual Studio's IIS Express there may be different behaviors I'd suspect.

Comment: @JBKing - production is using IIS, testing is using VS environment.

Comment: Configure your test environment to use IIS and see if the issue reproduces itself. I suspect it might as the VS version of IIS may deal with cookies slightly differently to be more "developer friendly" in a sense.

Comment: I do not have IIS installed on the test environment only on the production server.

Comment: VS environment (if you are talking about Cassini) is **so much** different than IIS. IIS Express is a better option to test your solution. But if you want to perform real test before production, use real IIS.

Comment: One more thing: you should consider Cassini as deprecated.